# Deferencing AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift, pointers

I want to get the list of all known classes with the Objective-C runtime function `objc_copyClassList()`:

```
var count = UInt32(0)
let classList = objc_copyClassList(&count)
```

`count` returns something like 3900. `classList` is an object of type `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<AnyObject.Type>>`.

How do I iterate through `classList` to get the names of all those 3900 classes with `class_getName()`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out myself:

```
var count = UInt32(0)
let classList = objc_copyClassList(&count)

for i in 0..<Int(count) {
    let cName = class_getName(classList[i])
    let classname = NSString(CString: cName, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print(className)
}
```